# My struct isn't working for decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift

been using swift 3 for sometime, till i updated my Xcode which came with swift 4, and with that i had to start using encodable decodable , but i'm having a hard time generating structs to decode. This is the json i'm trying to turn into an object

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "message": "Valid request",
    "data": {
        "user_id": "16",
        "first_name": "Hamidouh",
        "last_name": "Semix",
        "other_name": null,
        "fullname": "Hamidouh Semix",
        "alias": null,
        "about": "",
        "sex_id": "1",
        "sex": "Male",
        "birth_date": "1989-08-17 00:00:00",
        "relation_status_id": null,
        "relation_status": null,
        "relation_user_id": null,
        "relation_user_first_name": null,
        "relation_user_last_name": null,
        "relation_user_fullname": null,
        "location": null,
        "contact": null,
        "profile_pic": "698",
        "profile_folder_name": "profile-picture",
        "profile_pic_filename": "PROFILE-IMG-UPLOAD-1-16-20171222101217.jpg",
        "cover_pic": "697",
        "cover_folder_name": "cover-picture",
        "cover_pic_filename": "COVER-IMG-UPLOAD-1-16-20171222100128.png",
        "followers_list": {
            "user_11": {
                "id": "11",
                "datetime": "2018-02-20 19:09:44"
            }
        },
        "following_list": {
            "user_1": {
                "id": "1",
                "datetime": "2018-03-01 09:53:24"
            },
            "user_3": {
                "id": "3",
                "datetime": "2018-02-19 09:18:18"
            },
            "user_24": {
                "id": "24",
                "datetime": "2017-12-22 09:58:17"
            },
            "user_260": {
                "id": "260",
                "datetime": "2018-02-19 09:18:16"
            }
        },
        "mutual_list": {
            "user_78": {
                "id": "78",
                "datetime": "2017-12-08 12:05:23"
            }
        },
        "request_counter": "0",
        "dream_destination_list": null,
        "hidden_content_list": null,
        "email": "semixss.hamidouh@gmail.com",
        "username": null,
        "password": "84bcec2f89a4f8cdd17b4a98d1a6cbf69bc9efe657d36a09b2d423fa3030772ab8ba9e24",
        "salt": "owkLO",
        "social_media_auth": null,
        "social_media_id": null,
        "date_created": "2017-08-18 14:00:22",
        "last_seen": "2018-03-16 13:53:57",
        "is_suspended": null,
        "is_notified": null,
        "approve_token": "8f82fbac62ded7260a3faa45460719a1390e3e216c6ebf3c4794f2da627138b9",
        "device_token": null,
        "language_id": null,
        "language_machine_name": null,
        "language_label": null,
        "active": "1"
    }
}
```

currently these are the structs i've been able to generate for above json

```
struct user : Decodable {
    let status: String
    let message: String
    let data: userData
}

struct userData : Decodable {

    let user_id: Int
    let first_name: String
    let last_name: String
    let other_name: String
    let fullname: String
    let alias: String
    let about: String
    let sex_id: Int
    let sex: String
    let birth_date: String
    let relation_status_id: Int
    let relation_status: String
    let relation_user_id: Int
    let relation_user_first_name: String
    let relation_user_last_name: String
    let relation_user_fullname: String
    let location: String
    let contact: String
    let profile_pic: Int
    let profile_folder_name: String
    let profile_pic_filename: String
    let cover_pic: Int
    let cover_folder_name: String
    let cover_pic_filename: String
    let followers_list: Int
    let following_list: Int
    let mutual_list: Int
    let request_counter: Int
    let dream_destination_list: Int
    let hidden_content_list: Int
    let email: String
    let username: String
    let password: String
    let salt: String
    let social_media_auth: String
    let social_media_id: Int
    let date_created: String
    let last_seen: String
    let is_suspended: String
    let is_notified: String
    let approve_token: String
    let device_token: String
    let language_id: Int
    let language_machine_name: String
    let language_label: String
    let active: Int

}
```

> This is the decoding code i've written to try and parse this

```
//send request to server

guard let loginUrl = URL(string: "https://xxxxxx.com/api/index.php/Auth/login") else {return}

//request url
var request = URLRequest(url: loginUrl)

// method to pass data
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let body = "username=\(usernameVar)&password=\(passwordVar)"
request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

//launch session
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

    guard let data = data else {return}

    do {
        //let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        //print(json)
      let userDetails = try JSONDecoder().decode(user.self, from: data)
      for details in userDetails  {
        print(details.message)
      }

    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
  }

  task.resume()
```

This is the error

typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: By convention, your struct names should start with an uppercase letter, so `User` and `UserData`. You aren't decoding all of the data in `UserData`, so you will need to provide a `CodableKeys` enum

Comment: @Connor, 

typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Several fields are null in the json but non-nullable in the swift object.

Comment: Then, `followers_list`, `following_list`, and `mutual_list` are objects in the json but Ints (!?) in the swift object

Comment: "Xcode isn't being very specific about what the error is. it just keeps skipping to catch and displaying the catch error" No. YOU are the one who keeps skipping to catch and displaying the catch error. You are printing out an obscene string instead of catching the actual _error_ and printing it out. You have only yourself to blame that you don't know what the problem is.

Comment: That error message would only make sense and your code would only compile if you were trying to decode an array of your struct.

Comment: And most or all of your `Int`s are actually `String`s containing an integer.

Comment: Display the contents of `data` in your completion handler for `session.dataTask()`. Make sure you're really getting the json you're expecting.

Comment: *"...with that i had to start using encodable decodable..."* You don't, really. `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` are available but older techniques still work.

Comment: Approx. half of the types are wrong. Be aware that everything in double quotes is always string, even `"12"` or `"false"`. And specify `CodingKeys` to get rid of all those ugly snake_case variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your error message to a more helpful error message Lol.

You haven't accounted for optional values in your json. Remember there is a difference between `String` and `String?` there are several values in your json payload that return nil. In your swift struct you need to mark those fields as `Optionals`.

You also have mismatched Types. All of your returned types are `String` or `String?` not `Int`. Those are just numbers returned as `String?`. There are also `Dictionary` types nested in this payload as well. The `followers_list` is a dictionary so you need to make a new struct with those properties, called `List` and in your `UserData` struct, set the type of those "lists" to `[String:List]`

Also when you're confused about what kind of error is being thrown while decoding, (and most of the CocoaTouch Framework) those are `NSErrors`. You can print the value of the error to the console and it'll tell you exactly what error is exiting the scope. IE:

```
 valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [__lldb_expr_20.user.(CodingKeys in _992B1F7B4C3E0BAC48AEA280B9410D72).data, __lldb_expr_20.userData.,
debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

The above error message tells you that `CodingKey...userData` was set to expect a `String` but there was `null` (nil).

Heres what your current struct should look like:

```
struct User : Decodable {
     let status: String
     let message: String
     let data: userData
 }

 struct List: Decodable {
    var id: String?
    var datetime: String?
 }

struct UserData : Decodable {

let user_id: String 
let first_name: String
let last_name: String
let other_name: String? 
let fullname: String
let alias: String? 
let about: String
let sex_id: String 
let sex: String
let birth_date: String
let relation_status_id: String? 
let relation_status: String?
let relation_user_id: String?
let relation_user_first_name: String?
let relation_user_last_name: String?
let relation_user_fullname: String?
let location: String?
let contact: String?
let profile_pic: String
let profile_folder_name: String
let profile_pic_filename: String
let cover_pic: String
let cover_folder_name: String
let cover_pic_filename: String
let followers_list: [String:List]
let following_list: [String:List]
let mutual_list: [String:List]
let request_counter: String
let dream_destination_list: List?
let hidden_content_list: List?
let email: String
let username: String?
let password: String?
let salt: String
let social_media_auth: String?
let social_media_id: String?
let date_created: String
let last_seen: String
let is_suspended: String?
let is_notified: String?
let approve_token: String
let device_token: String?
let language_id: String?
let language_machine_name: String?
let language_label: String?
let active: String
}
```

Loose the snake case and use `CodingKeys` to follow Swift Naming Conventions or use a public struct with the values you care about(You don't have to model the entire JSON payload) with a private struct that models the JSON and set the values with a  custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)`  [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45807479/8397048).

Comment: lol, about the error.. it was really frustrating. sorry about that.
your solution worked for me danke!

Comment: All good. I'd definitely look into custom decoding only the part of that payload that you'll actually need. That's a beast of a struct.